# How to download dependencies inside a maven plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-plugin, aether

What's the best way to download remote maven artifact from within a maven plugin while also supporting maven `2.2.x`<sup>1)</sup>, `3.0.x`, `3.1.x` and newer?

`Aether` seems a good candidate but it changed package namespace between `3.0.5` and `3.1` breaking compatibility.

There's pieces of information around,

- some pointing towards [maven-dependency-tree](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-dependency-tree/) (as suggested [in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17685441/can-a-maven-mojo-relying-on-aether-be-compatible-with-maven-3-0-x-and-3-1-x)) (how?)
- yet another to [jcbi](http://aether.jcabi.com/),
- [Another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440224/how-can-i-download-maven-artifacts-within-a-plugin) which I think uses `Aether` underneath and presumably suffers from the same version incompatibility problem
- Try to manually force your version of `Ather` based on the [ResolveArtifact](https://github.com/eclipse/aether-demo/blob/master/aether-demo-snippets/src/main/java/org/eclipse/aether/examples/ResolveArtifact.java) example
- Try to port the really [complex solution reflection solution from Apache Karaf](https://github.com/apache/karaf/blob/d53de84df42a98681bc4cbe4cdb9b226244e6bd9/tooling/karaf-maven-plugin/src/main/java/org/apache/karaf/tooling/features/DependencyHelperFactory.java)
- Some other util from [maven-shared](https://github.com/apache/maven-shared) ?

So what's the correct, or at least working, way to go on about this?

<sup>1) Where Maven `2.2.x` is a *nice to have* as pointed out by @khmarbaise [is EoL](http://maven.apache.org/maven-2.x-eol.html)</sup>

Comment: What kind of dependencies dou you need to download? Do you really need to support Maven 2.? Do you mean 2.0.X or 2.2.X ?

Comment: @khmarbaise, `2.2.x` and any artifact from e.g., central.

Comment: Take a look into maven-compat module which might help for this. You know that [Maven 2.2.1 is already EoL](http://maven.apache.org/maven-2.x-eol.html) ?

Comment: @khmarbaise, perhaps I can reword to the question to state that `2.2.x` is *nice to have* since still a lot of people are using it.

Comment: Maven 2.2.1 has reached it's EOL over five years ago. (Check http://maven.apache.org/maven-2.x-eol.html). It only makes sense to support 3.x.y. I haven't dealt with this in a while, but I think the Karaf option you quoted looks good. Alternatively, if you really must support 2.2.x, you could write your own utility class which switches between what you see in the Karaf helper and the way you would normally download them in 2.2.x.

Comment: @carlspring EoL for Maven 2.2.1 has been decided this year in February (see [dev list](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/VOTE-Maven-2-x-is-end-of-life-td5784522i20.html#a5785086)). Not five years ago.

Comment: Oh, you're actually right, I seem to have confused it with it's last release date. Either way, use of 2.2.1 should now be discouraged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're in a plugin and want to have another plugin invoked, the best solution - by far - is to use [Mojo Executor](http://timmoore.github.io/mojo-executor/). This way, you won't rewrite the maven-dependency-plugin ...
Considering the maven version issues, well, I guess you should indeed give up on maven 2.* support.

Comment: Interesting, my use case requires an `Artifact` instance, is that possible using the Mojo Executor?

Comment: Can you elaborate by "my use case requires an Artifact" ? You'll have to give maven dependencies plugin the maven coordinates of the artifact you want to download. Do you want the user of your plugin to provide these in their POMs ? If so, you can get some inspiration by looking at the source of dependencies mojos : their use of a Collection<ArtifactItem> (look the [AbstractFromConfigurationMojo](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/xref/org/apache/maven/plugin/dependency/fromConfiguration/AbstractFromConfigurationMojo.html))

Comment: Preferably I would like to download an artifact and then get a handle to it, for instance to be able to copy it to somewhere on the local file system.

Comment: You know this is exactly what [maven-dependency-plugin:copy mojo](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-mojo.html) allows you to do ? You don't even need custom code.